# Vpp voltage listed with a division symbol?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm reading a spec sheet of an intercom and it lists the electronic call signal with the following notation:

```
8÷12 Vpp
```

I get that Vpp is Voltage peak-to-peak. However I cannot figure out what exactly the min and max amplitude are.

This is the part on the actual sheet. From what I understand it's a Spanish manufacturer:
[image: Specs]

Comment: It probably is mean to be a ± sign.

Comment: Maybe "tilde" ~ symbol? Meaning that "Can be between 8 and 12 Vpp".

Comment: It could also mean 12Vpk-pk biased at 8V since it's obviously an audio amplifier type device. That would be 8V +-6V

Comment: I think it just means *from* 8 *to* 12

Comment: Get your scope out and measure it. Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: I found myself facing exactly the same question when reading the specifications on [this](https://www.sferalabs.cc/iono-arduino/) page